# Variable HTML table cell height?

Tags: html, html-table

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><img src="image.jpg" /></th>
        <td>row1 column2</td>
        <td>row1 column3</td>
        <td>row1 column4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Results**
If the height of the img is equal to 10px, the height of all cells in that row equals 10px.
Adding a border to the td's results in the td's looking taller then the img.
Note: the img is contained in a th because I do not want a border around the img, only the td's.

**Desired Results**
[image: Link to image]

As displayed in the image above, the height of the td's should be adjustable so that their top and bottom borders can be aligned with the img.

**Research**
Using CSS to specify a height on the td's only works if the height is larger then the height of the img (in other words, the td's cannot be smaller then the img).
Additional research indicates that this is just the way tables work.

Comment: This is confusing me: "the height of the td's should be adjustable so that their top and bottom borders can be aligned with the img". Could you attempt to elaborate what you mean by that?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Hopefully this clarifies: notice that the top and bottom of the image is aligned with the top and bottom borders of each table cell (everything is the same height).

Comment: I think I understand the problem now. Do you *want* to use tables for this layout for any particular reason? I suspect it would be easier to do using `<div>` tags and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, in a table, the `<td>` elements are all the same size within a row, that is the purpose of the rows, you can align the cell contents within the row, but otherwise the row will have a consistent height.  The height of the row defaults to the maximum height of any cell within it.  Horizontal borders run with rows generally.

The only way to alter this really is to use `rowspan` with additional rows thrown in for positioning, but that is ugly in the extreme.

Do keep in mind that tables are for tabular data only, and should generally be avoided for other purposes, particularly layout.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand, you want border on the "inside" instead of the "outside"?

This is easily accomplished with CSS and `div`s, setting a negative `margin` equal to the `border-width`.

Is there a reason you're using `table`s?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following CSS properties to make the border-added boxes behave like Internet Explorer, in that the border width will be calculated into the box model size:

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;  
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;  
box-sizing: border-box;
```

source: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-did-internet-explorer-get-the-box-model-right/